# Converting categorical lists into a matrix with ranks

Tags: r

Sorry, again in for some basic question.

I have six lists of categorical data:

```
[1] A,B,C,D
[2] C,D,B,A
```

In the end, i would like to have a matrix, that looks like

```
  [1],[2]

[A] 1,4

[B] 2,3

[C] 3,1 

[D] 4,2
```

So that each column contains a list of the ranks of the categorical data. Thank you very much again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not clear about your input dataset

```
  l1 <- list(LETTERS[1:4], LETTERS[c(3:4, 2:1)])
  library(reshape2) 
  dat1 <- transform(melt(l1), indx=ave(seq_along(value), L1, FUN=seq_along))[,-2]
  split(dat1$indx, dat1$value)
  # $A
  #[1] 1 4

  # $B
  #[1] 2 3

  # $C
  #[1] 3 1

  # $D
  #[1] 4 2
```

If you need a matrix output

```
  do.call(rbind,split(dat1$indx, dat1$value))
```

#### Update

Or you could use `mapply`

```
  res2 <- mapply(match, rep(list(LETTERS[1:4]),length(l1)), l1)
  rownames(res2) <- LETTERS[1:4]
   res2
  #   [,1] [,2]
  #A    1    4
  #B    2    3
  #C    3    1
  #D    4    2
```

Or using `sapply` contributed by @alexis_laz

```
  res3 <- sapply(l1, function(x) match(LETTERS[1:4], x))
  rownames(res3) <- rownames(res2)
```

Or, in this case:

```
   sapply(l1, order)
   #      [,1] [,2]
   #[1,]    1    4
   #[2,]    2    3
   #[3,]    3    1
   #[4,]    4    2
```

Comment: +1 for the `match`; it seems the most appropriate. You could, perhaps, make it tidier with `sapply(l1, function(x) match(LETTERS[1:4], x))`?

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
a <- c(toupper(letters[1:4]))
b <- c("C","D","B","A")
n <- length(a)

dfs <- list(a, b)
ranks <- rep(list(seq(n)), length(dfs))

for(i in 1:length(ranks)){
  names(ranks[[i]]) <- dfs[[i]]
  ranks[[i]] <- ranks[[i]][order(names(ranks[[i]]))]
}

sapply(ranks, FUN = function(x) x)
```